# Why do I have a digest mismatch for a specific docker image?

Tags: docker

I've pulled a specific docker node alpine image

```
$ docker pull node:16.6.0-alpine3.14

16.6.0-alpine3.14: Pulling from library/node
5843afab3874: Pull complete 
fe3c641c07b1: Pull complete 
177e54153713: Pull complete 
8d2e094674ea: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:78cfbade13b9bed05f652e43d2928940dcca79d729682c5c1a046f5bf5a1158a
Status: Downloaded newer image for node:16.6.0-alpine3.14
docker.io/library/node:16.6.0-alpine3.14
```

on my ubuntu machine and for that I do get the digest `sha256:78cfbade13b9bed05f652e43d2928940dcca79d729682c5c1a046f5bf5a1158a`

But looking at the [docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/layers/node/library/node/16.6.0-alpine3.14/images/sha256-17dcbd28b3cbf5cc7ecc7d09ea62f8ba2a39fb3f2a9af7a2031f7706c120ab25?context=explore) I do not find this sha digest.
So why is there this mismatch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The digest reported on the pull command is for the manifest list. The digest reported in the Hub UI is for the individual platform image. There are various ways you can get the manifest list to see the digest for the manifest list matches what you pulled, and also that the individual manifests match what is shown on the Hub UI. `docker manifest inspect` exists in the docker CLI (but may require enabling experimental mode). Or there are a variety of standalone tools. From my [regclient](https://github.com/regclient/regclient) tool you can run:

```
$ regctl image manifest --list node:16.6.0-alpine3.14
Name:        node:16.6.0-alpine3.14
MediaType:   application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json
Digest:      sha256:78cfbade13b9bed05f652e43d2928940dcca79d729682c5c1a046f5bf5a1158a

Manifests:

  Name:      docker.io/library/node@sha256:e97343440257d8ce09817bcb27b509ff85e156bee1cee7b95ef16fa0065552f3
  MediaType: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json
  Platform:  linux/amd64

  Name:      docker.io/library/node@sha256:17dcbd28b3cbf5cc7ecc7d09ea62f8ba2a39fb3f2a9af7a2031f7706c120ab25
  MediaType: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json
  Platform:  linux/arm/v6     

  Name:      docker.io/library/node@sha256:c4e267c8b28ac88889e59d7ced098ea6e309846b4a74b80595521851127333b4
  MediaType: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json
  Platform:  linux/arm/v7

  Name:      docker.io/library/node@sha256:792e757cf72a8aaf6d469fda1ec6c1d794fda9b37928ef7251c71384198e1682
  MediaType: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json
  Platform:  linux/arm64/v8

  Name:      docker.io/library/node@sha256:0a4f0e28ff0fcdff7bed018a6f553ac9952b5d2eadc264baabfc9a8ed4a38bb7
  MediaType: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json
  Platform:  linux/ppc64le
```

Comment: How do I know which platform I have to choose? Or how do I see, which one has been pulled exactly on my machine?

Comment: @user3142695 in `docker info` there are fields for OSType and Architecture. There's a bit of mapping between that and the platform field, e.g mine says linux and x86_64, which I map to linux/amd64. When you inspect a pulled image with `docker image inspect` you'll see OS and Architecture there that tells you which has been pulled.

Answer (score 0):

Docker CLI always shows top level digest. which is embedded in manifest.json file inside the image.

you can refer this open issue for more information:

https://github.com/docker/hub-feedback/issues/1925

Though i am not full agree by discussion. whole purpose of digest to provide security by matching the digest which is not the case with Docker hub.